# group on mongodb filtering by any field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to make a group query on mongodb (using mongoose) filtering by any other different field than the group criteria. I have this by the moment:

```
usersDB.aggregate().group (
    {_id: '$residence', total: { $sum: 1 } } 
).exec(function (err, result) {
        if(err) res.send(err);
        else res.send(result);
});
```

And it works... it shows me for example:

```
[{"_id":"Javea","total":40},{"_id":"Benissa","total":28},{"_id":"Calpe","total":41},{"_id":"Teulada","total":14}]
```

But now, what I want to do is filtering too by date of last visit (last_visit is other field of UsersDB). I tried this:

```
    usersDB.find({$and:[{last_visit:{$lt:date}}, {last_visit:{$gt:date.setMonth(3)}}]}).aggregate().group(
    {_id: '$residence', total: { $sum: 1 } }).exec(
    function (err, result) {
        if(err) res.send(err);
        else res.send(result);
    });
```

And of course... it doesn't work!!

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the filtering within the aggregation pipeline using the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match) operator stage:

```
var start = date,  end = date;
end.setMonth(3);
var query = { "last_visit": { "$lt": end, "$gt": start } };

usersDB.aggregate()
       .match(query)
       .group({"_id": "$residence", "total": { "$sum": 1 } })
       .exec(function (err, result) {
            if(err) res.send(err);
            else res.send(result);
       });
```

Answer (score 3):

in mongo shell, it look's like:

```
db.users.aggregate([
{ $match : { $and [{last_visit:{$lt:date}}, {last_visit:{$gt:date.setMonth(3)}}]}},
{ $group : { _id: '$residence', total: { $sum: 1 } }}
]);
```